# jQuery's ajax "always" function jqXHR object doesnt Exists?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a handler  : (jQuery ver = 1.7)

Which return **something**.

[image]

Im calling this handler via ajax :

[image]

I know that the always method should get an object  like the complete func :

> complete(jqXHR, textStatus)          ..........//(jQuery Documentation)

**But** 
when I Try to alert:

obj.readyState     `or`
obj.status      `or`
obj.statusText     `or` 
obj.responseText     - I get **UNDEFINED**.

**When** I write `alert(obj)` it gives me 'aaa'.

**I need access to obj.readyState       , obj.status       etc...**

Why dont I get a valid object?

All I want is to check it had **200** return code.

What am i missing ?

Comment: Can you verify that the ajax call is returning, success or failure?

Comment: @Zero21xxx it Does go in success. but It also go to Always ( which is fine)  but i need access to the object in the `always` object.

Comment: Try changing `.always(function(obj))` to `.always(function(a,b,c))` just to see if maybe your function definition is wrong and other parameters are being passed but there isn't anything to store them in.

Comment: look at oleg g.'s answer, i works perfectly well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `always` callback has 3 parameters: **data**, **textStatus**, **jqXHR** what you are looking for is the third one -  **jqXHR**

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "TestHandler.ashx", async: false }).always(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert(data);             // aaa
        alert(jqXHR.statusText); // 200
        alert(jqXHR.status);     // OK
    });
});
```

Comment: This only works on success - the arguments are different on failure.

Comment: Please refer to @Mnebuerquo's answer, which explains how the **parameters vary depending on the response**.

Answer (score 9):

I'm answering this because the accepted answer does not tell the whole story. As I have just been trying to figure out a similar issue, I want to share with future google searchers and save them some time.

The jquery .always() function takes three parameters.

From the documentation:

```
jqXHR.always(function( data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown ) { });
```

When the ajax call succeeds, the .always() function is this:

```
function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ){...}
```

When the ajax call fails, the .always() function is this:

```
function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){...}
```

This is a really annoying problem in jquery, and it has been reported numerous times. This will probably not be fixed due to the backwards compatibility problems involved. See the bug report ticket here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11548

My solution is to determine which parameter is which when the .always() function is called. I could have used the textStatus parameter since it should be "success" in the first case. I instead decided that it would be safer to check the properties of the parameter to decide if it was a jqXHR object.

Here is some sample code which decides if this is a jqXHR object or not:

```
function isXHR(maybe)
{
    if(!maybe)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(! ('readyState' in maybe) )
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(! ('responseText' in maybe) )
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(! ('status' in maybe) )
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(! ('statusText' in maybe) )
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'm checking to see if the object has the appropriate properties, and if it does then it must be the jqXHR parameter.

```
function( first, textStatus, last)
{
    var my_jqXHR = null;
    var data = null;
    var errorThrown = null;
    if(isXHR(first))
    {
        my_jqXHR = first;
        errorThrown = last;
    }
    if(isXHR(last))
    {
        my_jqXHR = last;
        data = first;
    }
    var status = my_jqXHR.status;
    // do something with status
    ...
}
```

There may yet be a better way to do this, and a future version of jquery may give us a different callback function with more consistent arguments, but this solution is working in my code right now.

Comment: THIS. THIS SHOULD BE THE ACCEPTED ANSWER. SORRY FOR SHOUTING.

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify, since I can't comment, .always() doesn't take 3 parameters: .always() takes whatever parameters the promise sends when it's resolved or rejected.  In the case of .always() handling an ajax object, those indeed are the 3 parameters that the ajax object returns on success or fail and they are indeed in a confusing order.  But ajax isn't the only use for .always() or Deferreds in general and it's the fault of the ajax module, not of .always() itself.

Note that if the order of parameters is really important to standardize, you can actually change them using .then()

```
$.ajax('http://whatever.com').then(null,function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){
    return $.Deferred().reject(jqXHR.responseJSON||jqXHR.responseText||error||null,textStatus,jqXHR)
}).always(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    //everything is in its right place now,
    //though what "data" is can differ wildly depending what the error was
    console.log(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the documentation

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/

We can see that always does not define any parameters passed to the the callback.  Instead you will need to look at the context (`$(this)`) to find the data you want.

You can also use a closure.

---

Re comments:

I've looked at the source and it is interesting.  It seems the promise code keeps two list of callbacks as it does the promise code.  When there is a failure on the main list it moves to executing the 2nd list.  (Sort of like a roll back).  As it processes the promise callbacks it tries to keep the argument list stable and consistent by passing the last known good arguments. This is why you are seeing the some data there.

In your case, my guess is the json parsing failed.  It still has the string it was trying to parse so you see that as an argument.

In any case, if you use `this` you will see consistency in data and type with both success and failure.  I expect this is leading practice when using the promise code.  It is the only way to know exactly what you are going to get in the argument list of a promise callback.

Comment: so how does he alerts me 'aaa' when i alert the obj ?

Comment: I'd say undocumented feature, side effect or bug... not sure -- guess I could look at the source.  So could you :D

Comment: @RoyiNamir - I've added some more comments about this issue above.

Comment: ` json parsing failed` ? I sent a text not json. How do I get the 200 ack ?